# R: convert a varialble 'difftime' in seconds to a variable 'difftime' in days

Tags: r, time

I have the following vector`x` of class `difftime` expressing some time spans in seconds:

```
> x
Time differences in secs
[1]       0       0 7948800       0

> class(x)
[1] "difftime"
```

I would like to convert the variable so as to express every value in days instead of seconds

How could I get it?

Comment: How do you get the `x` value ? `difftime` function has an option to set `units = "days"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use `units=` as RonakShah suggested,

```r
x <- difftime(Sys.time() + c(0, 100, 3*86400), Sys.time(), units = "days")
x
# Time differences in days
# [1] 0.000000000 0.001157407 3.000000000
```

or change the units after the fact.

```r
x <- difftime(Sys.time() + c(0, 100, 3*86400), Sys.time())
x
# Time differences in secs
# [1]      0    100 259200
units(x) <- "days"
x
# Time differences in days
# [1] 0.000000000 0.001157407 3.000000000
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `as.numeric` and then convert to difftime using `units="days"` in both. If a numeric output is ok then omit `as.difftime` at the end of the pipeline.

```
# test input
secs <- as.difftime(rep(7948800, 3), units = "secs")

secs |> as.numeric(units = "days") |> as.difftime(units = "days")
## Time differences in days
## [1] 92 92 92
```